# A custom style with pure CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a style using CSS and HTML. My desire style is something similar to this.

[image]

Most of things of that style have been done with pure CSS and HTML.

This is my CSS -

```
.filter-box {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 3% 0 2%;
    width :29%;

    > .main-cat {      
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 25px;
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;

        > h3 {
            margin: 0;
        }
    }

    > .main-cat:after {
        border-bottom: 15px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border-left: 15px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-top: 15px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        content: "";
        height: 0;
        margin-top: -15px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -14px;
        top: 50%;
        width: 0;
    }

    > .main-cat:first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    > .sub-cat {
            background: #FF9000;
            margin-left: 25px;
            margin-top: 5px;
            padding: 8px 10px;
            text-align: right;

        > h4 {
            margin: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is when I am trying to display a let border with a bold circle bullet on the left side of the sub category DIV.

Can any body tell me is this possible with pure CSS and HTML without using any image?

This is my code so far: [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/macicunu/1/edit?html,css,output)

Any comments would be greatly welcome.

Thank You.

Comment: One suggestion would be to change your `sub-cat` divs to `li`s wrapped in a `ul`.

Comment: The code in the question is *not* pure CSS.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela less http://lesscss.org/ generates pure CSS, it is a preprocessor that can be very helpfull to use in certain cases

Comment: @GCyrillus, the code in the question still isn’t pure CSS, contrary to what it says. Thus, it is also unclear whether a pure CSS solution is asked for.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela *`Can any body tell me is this possible with pure CSS and HTML without using any image?`* it is quiet clear to me :) , for the preprocessor it is a point of view, my point is that it ends up as CSS served to browser :), your point of view can be different , no problem :)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela : how is this not pure CSS?

Comment: CSS checker (to see whether some code is pure CSS): http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/4LB5t/***

*CSS*:

```
.sub-cat:before {
    content: ' ';
    border-left: 1px solid white; 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px; height: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px; margin: 0px; margin-top: -8px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.sub-cat:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 8px; height: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 36px; margin-top: -8px;
}
```

**Update**:

*Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/4LB5t/1/*

Just increase the height on `.sub-cat:before`.

**Update 2**:

*Demo 3: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/4LB5t/2/*

Added your horizontal border as well. The only changes in the css are:

```
.sub-cat:before {
    ...
    border-bottom: 1px solid white; 
    margin-top: -26px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

You have to tweak and tune the styles to achieve what you want. Hope that helps.

Comment: abhitalks, yes it is very close. but there is a horizontal border too.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibilities would be to use background-image (gradients) and bullets of list-item , resized via font-size : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kCFof)**

The CSS update could be :*(see comment for explanation )*

```
.filter-box {
    background:linear-gradient(to right,
  transparent 15px,
  white 15px,
  white 17px,
  transparent 17px); /* draws the vertical bar aside list-items */
}
  background:linear-gradient( /* draw orange background */
    to right,
 transparent 40px , 
    #FF9000 40px),
    linear-gradient(/* draw middle white bar */
      to bottom,
      transparent 49%,
      white 48%,
      white 52%,
      transparent 51%
      ) right no-repeat;
  background-size:
      auto auto/* no need to resize first gradient */, 
      95% 100% /*reduce width of second gradient */;
  display:list-item;/* lests get a round bullet if this is not a li */
  color:white; /* give color to bullet */
  font-size:2.2em;/* resize bullet */
  list-style-position:inside;/* keep bullet inside element */
}
.filter-box > .sub-cat > h4 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size:0.6em;/* resize to a normal font-size from  em value inherited */
  display:inline-block;/* stands aside bullet */
  text-align: right;/* align to right */
  width:85%;/* keep min/max-width under control*/
}
```

**Notice:** no pseudo elements involved, gradient can be image for better compatibilitie and dispatch within main container , sub container and title for the background-color to increase compatibiliti with old browser.

As mentionned earlier , [this menu/list deserve to be build from an HTML list](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gimFG).

Comment: +1: this is a better solution. it scales well with variable content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:before` and `:after` elements in the sub-category to design the circle and left border.

Use the :before to make the circle as @megha outlined, and position it with the vertical center of the sub-cat.

Put the position of the `.subcat` as `position: relative`, so that you can define the positions of the absolutely positioned `:before` and `:after` in relation to the left edge of `.subcat`

Then use the :after and style it as

`width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -10px`

Hope this helps

---

Look at this pen. I have modified some of the styles in the answer to make it work. (SCSS syntax)
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJepq

```
  .sub-cat {
    background: #FF9000;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    &:before {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #ff9000;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 12px;
      left: -20px;
    }
    &:after {
      width: 2px;
      top: -5px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: -16px;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #ff9000;
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Kumar Harsh, I tried with your suggestion. But can't get it to work. This is [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/macicunu/1/edit?html,css,out)

Answer (score 1):

Using `:after` and `:before` pseudo element you can achieve the result.

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rodofuga/2/edit)**.

**Here is the CSS would be required.**

```
.sub-cat:before{
content: "";
position:absolute;
left:25px;
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
border-radius: 50%;
background:white;
margin-top: 5px;
}

.sub-cat:after{
content: "";
position:absolute;
top:55px;
left:29px;
height:21%;
border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.sub-cat h4:before{
content: "  ";
position:absolute;
left:32px;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
transform:rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
border-right: 1px solid white;}

.sub-cat h4:after{
content: "  ";
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:4px;
position:absolute;
border-bottom: 8px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
border-left: 8px solid #000000;
border-top: 8px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A circular bullet can be created using the html :

```
<div id="circle"></div>
```

and its corresponding css

```
#circle
{
width:10px;
height:10px;
border-radius:5px;
background-color:white;
}
```

I am unable to understand what "let border" means.Hope this helps!

Comment: Look at left side of sub content divs that I have upload above. There is a border with circular bullets.